# How do I do the Mario Face Glitch In SM64

Tags: super-mario-64

I've heard of many people performing a glitch in SM64 where they stretch Mario's face near the beginning of the game and it sticks like that. How do I perform this glitch (and no, I dont mean just pulling his face a little bit)

Comment: Can you provide anymore detail about how this glitch affects the game? When the game starts up, Mario's big head will show up and you can pull and tug on it, stretching him out. If you a hold a certain button (cant remember which one) the face will stay like that until you release the button. That's the only thing I know of but as it stands, I cant tell if what I said answers your question, or if you're asking how to make the stretched face persist into the actual game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, if I understood what you meant, that is not even a glitch.

Pressing (A) will allow you to stretch the face, and normally it will return to normal as soon as you release the button. In order to keep it stretched you have to hold the (R) trigger **before releasing (A)**.